# update all duplicate rows with different values in pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update duplicate rows with different values in same table.
my table is

```
table(id, phoneId(int), deviceId(int), userId(int))
```

There are some records with same `deviceId` or `phoneId`. for example

```
id   phoneId   deviceId    userId
1    23        3434        1235
2    23        5453        235   <---- same phoneId with 1 record 
3    43        5453        2343  <---- same deviceId with 2 record
4    23        3434        6347  <---- same deviceId and phoneID with 1 record
```

what i need to change is - if `phoneId` is not unique, set `phoneId` to `userId`(from this row). same at deviceId. (if `deviceId` is not unique, set `deviceId` to `userId`)
so the final result should be this

```
id   phoneId   deviceId    userId
1    23        3434        1235
2    235       5453        235   <---- phoneId changed to userId
3    43        2343        2343  <---- phoneId changed to userId
4    6347      6347        6347  <---- phoneId and deviceId changed to userId
```

Comment: The problem is that you can get chains . . . P1 --> D1 --> P2 --> D2.  What do you want to do about these?

Comment: sorry, can you please be more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just update duplicated phoneids and then duplicated deviceids (assuming that table name is "t")

```
UPDATE t SET phoneid=userid FROM (SELECT count(*),phoneid FROM t GROUP BY phoneid HAVING count(*)>1) AS foo WHERE t.phoneid=foo.phoneid;
UPDATE t SET deviceid=userid FROM (SELECT count(*),deviceid FROM t GROUP BY deviceid HAVING count(*)>1) AS foo WHERE t.deviceid=foo.deviceid;
```